# How to recover view from View.gone. setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) not working after using 'android:visibility="gone"' in xml

Tags: java, android, xml

My issue:
In my xml file, I define android:visibility="gone" in the linear layout labelled as assess_layout_list. Then, in the onClick() of course_adapter_layout, the whole view, I set the visibility back to View.VISIBLE, which does not work, even though the Log call just before it works, the LinearLayout object called assess_list_layout is not null, and it does work when I define the visibility="invisible" in the xml file. I want it to be gone at first though, and visible after clicking as this fits the design of the app.

Here is my course_adapter_view.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/course_adapter_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="left"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/course_header_background">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/course_color_circle"/>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/course_adapter_course_code"
            android:text="TextView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/course_adapter_course_title"
            android:text="TextView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/assess_list_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/course_body_background"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        >


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/course_adapter_assess_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="More" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="New"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my CourseListAdapter.java file that I use to create each view for each course in the list of courses, minus the usual stuff:

```
package com.example.schoolplanner2.adapters;


public class CourseListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Course> {
  private static final String TAG = "CourseListAdapter";

  private Context context;
  int mResource;

  public CourseListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<Course> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = context;
    mResource = resource;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    // get info
    String course_code = getItem(position).getCourseCode();
    Double course_grade = getItem(position).getCurrentGrade();

    // make inflater and inflate the layout
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View v = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);


    TextView tv_course_code = v.findViewById(R.id.course_adapter_course_code);
    TextView tv_course_title = v.findViewById(R.id.course_adapter_course_title);

    tv_course_code.setText(course_code);
    tv_course_title.setText(String.valueOf(course_grade));

    // add on click to each list view element
    LinearLayout layout = v.findViewById(R.id.course_adapter_layout);
    layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.i(TAG, "List view element has been clicked " + course_code);

       
        // expand the view to include a new fragment
        LinearLayout assess_list_layout = view.findViewById(R.id.assess_list_layout);
        assess_list_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // get the list view and add each course to the course view
        ListView assessment_list_view = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.course_adapter_assess_list);
        AssessmentListAdapter assessAdapter = new AssessmentListAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.assessment_adapter_view, getItem(position).getAssessmentList(), getItem(position));
        assessment_list_view.setAdapter(assessAdapter);
      }
    });

    return v;
  }
}
```

Please let me know if there is any more information you need. Will also take suggestions on other ways of accomplishing the same thing. Thanks for your help.
~Seth.

Edit: when the assess_list_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) is outside of the onClick it does work.

Further Edit: Things I have tried so far to no avail:

- moving the location of where I define the LinearLayout componenent
- calling invalidate() on parent view
- using runOnUiThread()
- changing view to v in the line where I attempt to findViewById for assess_list_layout, they are the same thing so it does not help.
- calling requestLayout() on assess_list_layout

Update: I have now managed to get the assess_list_layout section to appear when the course_adapter_layout is clicked on. The only problem now is that the view does not take up anymore space on the screen, it just turns into a scrollable view that can be scrolled up and down on to see the whole view.
Also, when I scroll to fast, it resets the view back to the way it was on bootup.

Comment: why not you find your `linear layout` in where you finding all views may this help

Comment: try to call  invalidate() on parent view

Comment: use runOnUiThread and place your assess_list_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); in its run method.

Comment: @ Danish - So I have the context as one of the arguments of the constructor, which I casted as an Activity, which I then used to call runOnUiThread, in which I called setVisibility(View.VISIBLE), which did not work.

Comment: Just like you found the `R.id.course_adapter_layout` view find `R.id.assess_list_layout` , like this `LinearLayout assess_list_layout = v.findViewById(R.id.assess_list_layout);` Notice the `v.findViewById` instead of `view.findViewById` . Also move it outside the `onClick` event

Comment: Changing view to v and v to view does not help, they are the same thing.

Comment: If the code works outside the click listener then it may be related to layout. Call `requestLayout()` on the clicked view group to see if that is the problem. Also, you say the id is "assess_layout_list" in the description but it is "assess_list_layout" in the code.

Comment: The xml which you added here is it the row of `ListView`? If so then in each row you have `ListView`? Can you add more code to your `CourseListAdapter.java`

Comment: @SethHarlaar Did you get a solution for your problem?

Comment: @Cheticamp I called requestLayout() and it did not work

Comment: @akhilnair I'm not sure I understand what your asking, could you rephrase? and no, I have not

Comment: I am here trying to understand the problem and what you have done so far. In the question I see a layout xml file `course_adapter_view` does this layout represent each row of the ListView? Can you please add full code of your `CourseListAdapter.java` to get a better picture?

Comment: Yes, course_adapter_view represents a row in a ListView. It has two sections, the header section, which is the first nested LinearLayout, and the content section, which has id="assess_list_layout" and is the second nested LinearLayout. Keep in mind that assess_list_layout also contains a ListView, but it is a different one that the CourseAdapter is being used to fill out. CourseAdapter fills out a list of courses, with the layout course_adapter_view, and AssessmentListAdapter fills out the list with id="course_adapter_assess_list", which is in the content section of assess_list_layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.View Visibility not working**

The Visibility is not working because the view is not rendered initially. Remove the visibility gone in the xml and handle the visibility fully in the adapter class. In the 'assess_list_layout' linerlayout height can be  hardcode because inside this layout the listview height is already hardcoded. You can hardcode to 300 and check. This way will help the view to get the initial rendering.

**2. Scroll issue**

While scrolling the already visible 'assess_list_layout' view might be not visible. This is because we need to handle the visibility, this handling is similar to checkbox selection handling in listview. Hope the **Course** class is model class, in that add a another property named **isSelected** as boolean and set the default value to **false**. Please refer below the course class,

**Course Class**

```
public class Course {
private boolean isSelected = false;

public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        isSelected = selected;
    }

}
```

please refer the below code changes in the adapter class.

```
    public class CourseListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Course> {
      private static final String TAG = "CourseListAdapter";
    
      private Context context;
      int mResource;
    
      public CourseListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<Course> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        mResource = resource;
        }
    
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        // get info
        String course_code = getItem(position).getCourseCode();
        Double course_grade = getItem(position).getCurrentGrade();
    
        // make inflater and inflate the layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);
    
    
        TextView tv_course_code = v.findViewById(R.id.course_adapter_course_code);
        TextView tv_course_title = v.findViewById(R.id.course_adapter_course_title);
    
    //My Change
      // expand the view to include a new fragment
            LinearLayout assess_list_layout = view.findViewById(R.id.assess_list_layout);
    
    // get the list view and add each course to the course view
            ListView assessment_list_view = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.course_adapter_assess_list);
    
    assess_list_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    
    if (getItem().get(position).isSelected()) {
    assess_list_layout.setVisibility(View.Visible);
    AssessmentListAdapter assessAdapter = new AssessmentListAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.assessment_adapter_view, getItem(position).getAssessmentList(), getItem(position));
            assessment_list_view.setAdapter(assessAdapter);
    }
//My Change
    
        tv_course_code.setText(course_code);
        tv_course_title.setText(String.valueOf(course_grade));
    
        // add on click to each list view element
        LinearLayout layout = v.findViewById(R.id.course_adapter_layout);
        layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.i(TAG, "List view element has been clicked " + course_code);
    
           //My Change
            getItem().get(position).setSelected(true);          
            //My Change
            assess_list_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            
            AssessmentListAdapter assessAdapter = new AssessmentListAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.assessment_adapter_view, getItem(position).getAssessmentList(), getItem(position));
            assessment_list_view.setAdapter(assessAdapter);
          }
        });
    
        return v;
      }
    }
```

I have commented as **My Change** to find the difference in the code.

Comment: Good solution. I added a function to also switch the selected, and I also added some selection statements around the 'assess_list_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);' statement that you have inside the click listener to switch if its visible or not.

Answer (score 0):

**issue 1**

```java
// make inflater and inflate the layout
   LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
   View v = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);
```

you don't reuse view，which leads to inflate a new view every time when called getView()；As inflate() method is IO sensitive，it slow down the smoothness of scrolling ，trigger jank。

try this

```java
// make inflater and inflate the layout
        View v = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            v= inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);
        } else {
            v = convertView;
        }
```

**issue 2**

when scorll listview ,you need reset itemview state,add a  "expand" property to your **Course** bean ,when click item set **expand = true**;and then  add flowing code above layout.setOnClickListener

```java
v.findViewById(R.id.assess_list_layout).setVisibility( item.expand ? View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);
ListView assessment_list_view = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.course_adapter_assess_list);
if (item.expand) {
    AssessmentListAdapter assessAdapter = new  AssessmentListAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.assessment_adapter_view, 
   item.getAssessmentList(), item);
   assessment_list_view.setAdapter(assessAdapter);
}
```

**issue 3**

set setOnClickListener in **getView()** method , will create a new Clicker instance every time getView() called. use **listView.setOnItemClickListener()** instead

**tips:**

after all，you should use RecyclerView instead of ListView，which is a powerful UI widget